# Pushing my code and creating a PR shows others commit too. Why is that happening?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I am pushing my code and creating a PR using intelliJ IDE. When I am clicking on the link it provides, I see others commits too. I have checked I am pushing it to the right branch.

What I do -

1- Create a branch from say `feature-platform`

2- `git fetch / checkout` the branch from my IDE.

3- `git pull` (not necessary I think, but still I do.)

4- make changes and push.

This problem is killing me for a while.
What I do to resolve it is -

```
git log
git rebase -i <copy and paste the commit that I want to remove>~1
git push -f
```

PS - I am using Bitbucket.

Comment: You're creating the PR targeting `feature-platform`?

Comment: Yes @tgdavies. I am targeting the same branch.

Comment: The branch has commits which were made by others. The target branch does not have those commits.

Comment: Did you create your branch from the same branch you're now issuing a PR back into, or did you create your branch from some other feature branch that hasn't been merged yet?